# Magento: Getting the category description in a layout file?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created my own template file for category pages (like 2columns-left.phtml for example). In that file I want to display the description of the category I am in at some other place. How can I get the current categories description? I know its included in

```
$this->getChildHtml('content')
```

But its hard to get it from there. Is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($category) {
    $category->getDescription();
}
```

Ideally this would be encapsulated in a proper PHP method rather than used directly in the template.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! Do you also know how to remove the description part from the "content" part?